# Не могу подключить dial-up для Ubuntu.

Tags: ubuntu

Система не видит модема. Какой командой настроить соединение?**Добавлено**.Я подключал свою сотку, но не смог! В терминале я остановился на этом: ![снимок][1]Не смог завершить команду. Как это делается? Набирал `$ sudo wvdial` - не завершается!  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhAo4.png

Comment: какой модем,Е1550 или Е173?

Comment: Модем внутренний, в ноуте Acer Aspire 5610Z.Я зашёл на сайт: http://packages.ubuntu.com/Скачал новую прогу, старую удалил (её ставил через центр приложений)Модем определился, но не дозванивается до провайдера.                                           **Не могу загрузить фото!**

Comment: набор номера идет? что значит не дозванивается до провайдера, сбрасывает, занято или никто трубку не берет?

Comment: Я подключал свою сотку, но не смог!В терминале я остановился на этом: http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/2712/82432024.0/0_821fb_b0bd01a8_LНе смог завершить команду. Как это делается? Набирал $ sudo wvdialне завершается!

Comment: Когда отключаю USB модем, Dial-up начинает дозваниваться, но связь не устанавливается. Я сделал снимок экрана на уведомления вdial-up модема:http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/2712/82432024.0/0_8222b_6017999c_LЧто посоветуете?

Comment: Когда я с Vistы дозваниваюсь до провайдера, я слышу как телефон дребезжит.В этом случае ни него не происходит!

Answer (score 1):

[Настройка cоединение DIAL-UP в Ubuntu](http://linuxsoid.ucoz.com/publ/rukovodstvo_po_ubuntu/podrobnaja_informacija_dlja_novichkov/nastrojka_coedinenie_dial_up_v_ubuntu/8-1-0-900).

Answer (score 0):

Ты походу в тональном набираешь. Попробуйте импульсный набор